# Create delegate from constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, .net-4.5

Using reflection, I'm trying to create a delegate from a parameterless constructor like this:

```
Delegate del = GetMethodInfo( () => System.Activator.CreateInstance( type ) ).CreateDelegate( delType );

static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo( Expression<Func<object>> func )
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)func.Body).Method;
}
```

But I get this exception:
  "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."  What will work?

Note that [CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.createdelegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was moved, for this profile at least, since the previous version of .NET.  Now it's on MethodInfo.

Comment: Are you trying to create a delegate that invokes a parameterless constructor of a type where you only have a Type instance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As phoog points out a constructor doesn't "return" a value; plus you get information about it with `ConstructorInfo` and not `MethodInfo`; which means you can't create a delegate around it directly.  You have to create code that invokes the constructor and returns the value.  For example:

```
var ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
if (ctor == null) throw new MissingMethodException("There is no constructor without defined parameters for this object");
DynamicMethod dynamic = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty,
            type,
            Type.EmptyTypes,
            type);
ILGenerator il = dynamic.GetILGenerator();

il.DeclareLocal(type);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var func = (Func<object>)dynamic.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>));
```

Of course, if you don't know the type at compile time then you can only deal with `Object`...

Comment: My code is working this way. Thanks!  Can you also explain why your approach works but mine doesn't?  I was also trying to "create a delegate around" the constructor.

Comment: What is the meaning of `stloc.0` and `ldloc.0`? Imagine that you're holding in your hands something that you need, but to take it, you put it in a box, so that now you can get it out of there.

Comment: stdloc.0 means
`Pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores it in the local variable list at index 0.`

and ldloc.0 means
`Loads the local variable at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.`

The evaluation stack is like a register if you're familiar with machine language.

Comment: `DeclareLocal`, `Stloc_0` and `LdLoc_0` can be removed

Answer (score 11):

Try it out:

```
Dictionary<Type, Delegate> cache = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();
public T Create<T>()
{
    if (!cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var d))
        d = cache[typeof(T)]
            = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(
                Expression.New(typeof(T)),
                Array.Empty<ParameterExpression>())
            .Compile();
    return ((Func<T>)d)();
}
```

The reflection is too slow! Speed tests are there (in Russian): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860921/218063

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out. If you want parameters too, make sure the New call args are passed to the Lambda call. Given a ConstructorInfo, here's my code for a TResult constructor that takes a single T parameter:
'NewExpression newExpression = Expression.New(constructorInfo, Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)));
Func<T, TResult> constructorFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(newExpression, newExpression.Arguments.Cast<ParameterExpression>().ToArray()).Compile();'

Answer (score 3):

It would not be very useful to have a delegate that points to a constructor, since constructors do not have a return value.  The delegate would construct an object but give you no way of retaining a reference to it.

You can of course create delegates that return the newly-constructed object:

```
Func<object> theDelegate = () => new object();
```

You could also create a delegate from the `Invoke()` method of the constructor's `ConstructorInfo`

For other types of objects:

```
Func<string> theDelegate = () => new string('w', 3);
Func<SomeClassInMyProject> theDelegate = () => new SomeClassInMyProject();
```

The last line assumes there's an accessible parameterless constructor.

Update with `CreateDelegate()`

```
T CallConstructor<T>() where T : new() { return new T(); }
Delegate MakeTheDelegate(Type t)
{
    MethodInfo generic = //use your favorite technique to get the MethodInfo for the CallConstructor method
    MethodInfo constructed = generic.MakeGenericMethod(t);
    Type delType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(t);
    return constructed.CreateDelegate(delType);
}
```

Comment: I need a delegate, whose type exactly matches delType, that returns the created object.  This code doesn't help since the result is of type Func<object> and not delType.

Comment: @HappyNomad the code does return the exact type of the created object, since the object is created with the statement `new object()`.  I've added some examples of how to do this with other types.

Comment: @HappyNomad in response to your comment: if you don't know the type of the object at runtime, why do you need a strongly-typed delegate?

Comment: @HappyNomad And how do you propose to cast it to, for example, `Func<T>` if you don't know `T` at compile time?

Comment: A useful answer needs CreateDelegate( delType ) in it.  My original approach has that.  Peter's answer has that.  Yours doesn't.

Comment: No since I get the same exception that's mentioned in my question.

Comment: @HappyNomad it worked for me.  I suppose there is something going on with the security transparency in  your project.