# how create delegeate of a type which is not created

Tags: c#, system.reflection, reflection.emit

I'm using the system. reflection.Emit to implement google protocol message

[image]

I want to init a static field

```
class MessageA
{
   static MessageParser<MessageA> Parser = new MessageParser<MessageA>(()=>new MessageA())
}
```

now MessageA is not created  then i tried to get the constructor of  Func
it throws System.NotSupportedException with Message “Specified method is not supported.”
here my example

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var assembleBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Dynamic"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
var moduleBuilder = assembleBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Dynamic.dll");
var typeA = moduleBuilder.DefineType("classA");
typeA.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeA).GetConstructors();
```

How does the compiler do it?

Comment: `GetConstructors` will get the constructors defined for `Func<classA>`, which of course don't exist. However you don't need the constructor of a delegate, but a delegate for your constructor, do you? Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593630/create-delegate-from-constructor?

Comment: how can i get the constructor of Func<classA> i  need to create a delegate under the IL code

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain _"which of course don't exist."_ can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: `typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeA).GetConstructors();` implies, the following is valid: `var f = new Func<MyType>()`. You cannot **instantiate** delegate using a default-constructor. What you want is not the constructor of a delegate, but a delegate for a constructor.

Comment: _"implies, the following is valid"_ - I would say that no, it does not. It implies that `Func<T>` can have a constructor and as far as I know everything in C# has at least one. Also I'm not sure why you are talking about a paramaterless one.

Comment: sure, but not neccessarily a **paramaterless** (=default) one

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain yes, sure. But I'm not sure that OP needs a paramaterless one.

Comment: @GuruStron The only constructor for a `Func` accepts another `Func`. Even if OP's class has multiple ctor-args, that's not what the constructor of `Func` is for.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain maybe OP wants to generate the same as [compiler does](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjSAKwA8AlgHYAuAfIgB6IC8iCvy4QA3NRwBfWJKA===) .

Answer (score 1):

To mix existing und to be created types, `TypeBuilder` provides a few `static` helper methods. In this case you could use `TypeBuilder.GetConstructor`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var assembleBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Dynamic"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
var moduleBuilder = assembleBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Dynamic.dll");
var typeA = moduleBuilder.DefineType("classA");
typeA.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

var desiredCtorDefintion = typeof(Func<>).GetConstructors().First();
var constructedType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeA);
var ctor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(constructedType, desiredCtorDefintion);
```

`ctor` is of type `internal sealed class ConstructorOnTypeBuilderInstantiation : ConstructorInfo`
[source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Emit/XXXOnTypeBuilderInstantiation.cs,5a0480197668bae0)

Comment: sorry i ingored there is a static method  which is TypeBuilder.GetConstructor,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-a-generic-type-with-reflection-emit

Answer (score 0):

`typeA` is not a created type so it is not allowed to do that (`typeA.GetConstructors()` will also fail). Build type first:

```cs
var typeA = moduleBuilder.DefineType("classA");
typeA.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

// typeA.GetConstructors() will fail
var type = typeA.CreateType();

type.GetConstructors(); // typeA.GetConstructors() works too
typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(type).GetConstructors();
```

But to create a `Func<T>` from a constructor you actually don't need the func's constructor, you should be able to use any of methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600712/a-constructor-as-a-delegate-is-it-possible-in-c) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593630/create-delegate-from-constructor).

P.S.

Useful tool to see how compiler handle thigs is [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io). You can see both [decompilation to C#](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjSAKwA8AlgHYAuAfIgB6IC8iCvy4QA3NRwBfWJKA===) and [IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMALJgLIAUAlIcaSzAKwA8YAdsAHyYAHpgC8mBqIEIA3MxIBfVPKA===).

[This decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+QVgB5UA+RAMQEsBTAGwBNEBeRACgEonSA7KgdzXYBuWAF8gA==) should represent your scenario.

**UPD**

I would suggest just to create a helper class (in code) which will do what is needed (i.e. return `MessageParser` with func returning invocation of default ctor) and then use it to call via emit:

```cs
public class Helper
{
    public static MessageParser<T> GetDefaultMessageParser<T>() where T : new() => new MessageParser<T>(() => new T());
}
```

And generation:

```cs
var assembleBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Dynamic"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
var moduleBuilder = assembleBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Dynamic.dll");
var typeA = moduleBuilder.DefineType("classA");
var defaultConstructorBuilder = typeA.DefineTypeInitializer(); // define static ctor
var mpType = typeof(MessageParser<>).MakeGenericType(typeA);

var parserFieldBuilder = typeA.DefineField("Parser", mpType, FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Private);
var methodInfo = typeof(Helper)
    .GetMethod(nameof(Helper.GetDefaultMessageParser))
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeA);
var ctorGenerator = defaultConstructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ctorGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo);
ctorGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, parserFieldBuilder);
ctorGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var type = typeA.CreateType();

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var value = type.GetField("Parser",  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(new object[] { });
Console.WriteLine(value?.ToString()); // prints MessageParser`1[classA]
```

But in general I would recommend switching to [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) ([here my sandbox one](https://github.com/gurustron/default-record-ctor), for example) which will allow you to generate your class during compilation with, I would argue, much less effort and less error prone.

Comment: `// typeA.GetConstructors() will fail` vs `// typeA.GetConstructors() works too`?

Comment: after invoking typeA.CreateType();  it will be unable to change after type has been created

Comment: @Conner I assume that is the reason why you can't get constructors before finishing the type.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain yes. Building the type makes this work. I assume `CreateType` has side effect for builder itself too.

Comment: aaah, didn't know that... seems odd to me, but good to know

Comment: so what am i supposed to do, i tried to find the answer in the dotnet source code but no result it's complicated

Comment: @Conner are you sure you need to generate this in runtime? Or compile time will also do?

Comment: @Guru Stron   my plan was using CodeDom to compile but it's not supported in netcore6 i think using IL generator is the only way

Comment: @Conner please read my question carefully. If type was generated at compile time would it work for you?

Comment: @Guru Stron  i think it could

Comment: @Conner see the update. Also another possible trick - get constructor from generic type and then use `MakeGeneric...` on it.

Comment: @Guru Stron still does not work, did you try?

Comment: @Conner of course I have tried. Works fine for me. [Check it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0TREEv) yourself.